# passing path as a variable in powershell script

Tags: powershell

I want to pass path as a varibale(Read-host) in my powershell script. It is not working giving error as

Cannot find path  because it does not exist

My code

```
$a=read-host
$b=read-host
Copy-item $a $b
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard for us to really figure out the issue since we don't know exactly what you are typing in. Put the code below into a script to see if the paths are valid or not:

```
$a = Read-Host
$b = Read-Host
'Copying from {0} to {1}' -f $a, $b
Copy-Item $a $b
```

Answer (score 0):

use the Test-Path it returns a boolean if the path exists

```
if(Test-Path $a){
     Copy-Item $a $b
}
```